# Running fast calculations on database entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

We are working on a asp.net mvc 4 project on .net 4.5 framework using Entity Framework 6 and sql server.

We need to run calculations (almost every new version we upload) on entities (of type 'A') retreived from database (a couple of thousands). So we put some code in the seed method (which runs every app start) and with a simple foreach loop got unsatisfying results. (about 2 seconds for every entity).

When we tried moving the code inside the seed method to run in parallel we got alot of wrong results and excpetions were thrown.

(This calcultions on entities of type 'A' are dependent on alot more entities to be loaded from the database in runtime or eagerly loaded. (Tried both)

I read about EF and parallelism and i know it's not realy a good idea but i still need advice about how to improve this result...

Should i work more on the parallel execution or it's a wrong path to continue on?

code example :

```
                 var assets = context.Assets
                    .Include(x => x.YitraLefiGilPrisha)
                    .Include(x => x.ZihuiKisui)
                    .Include(x => x.PirteiTaktziv.Select(p => p.Yitrot.Select(y => y.PerutYitrot)))
                    .Include(x => x.PirteiTaktziv.Select(p => p.PerutMivneDmeiNihul))
                    .Include(x => x.PirteiTaktziv.Select(p => p.PirteiOved))
                    .Include(x => x.PirteiTaktziv.Select(p => p.PirteiHaasaka))
                    .ToList();
                foreach (var asset in assets)
                {
                    Logger.Debug("Running Procedures on asset : " + asset.Id);
                    repo.RunProceduresAndCalculationsOnAsset(asset);
                    Logger.Debug("Finished Running on asset : " + asset.Id);
                }
```

Comment: so this is about mass updating?

Comment: Skip EF and run a bulk update statement instead.

Comment: Or implement a stored procedure or anything... ORM is not good for mass operations...

Comment: even if you get the parallelism right it would only increase performance by a factor... with a stored procedure you will get faster results in any case

Comment: there are a few ways you can improve performance of bulk operations in Entity Framework, but without some example of your code, it's hard to make a suggestion on which is right for your scenario.   You could, for example, turn off the context change detection, which adds overhead; `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`.  Just make sure you turn it back on when you are done with the bulk operations... You could also use `AsNoTracking()` on your entities, or, as other people have suggested, use a Stored Procedure.

Comment: more than likely, your performance here is related to how you are looping through the objects and performing your updates.  without at least *some* idea of the code you have, a more concrete answer isn't really possible.

Comment: @Claies i added a sample of the main loop in the seed method. The rest of the code inside the RunProceduesAndCalculationsOnAsset is quite a lot  and probably cab be optimized as well.. but still i dont think it will be fast enought even after we will do improvements.

Comment: in this instance, I would say that the automatic change detection is probably at fault for the poor performance here.  Every time you change a property on an asset, the `DetectChanges()` event would fire.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker.detectchanges(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Including the source for RunProceduresAndCalculationsOnAsset would have helped.

a. Abandoning EF is not the answer ... it is just plumbing to the database.
b. Parallelism probably isn't the answer ... but you won't know that until you have pinned down the true bottleneck.

This is where I would start.

1. Since your doing the eager loading, determine if it really working.  Are there a lot of round trips to the database.  You may be using an entity that needs lazy loading.  Use SQL Profiler or EF6 profiling.
2. If the round trips to the database have been determined to not be the issue ... then use Visual Studio to profile the code to determine the CPU bottleneck.

Then work from there.